# Remove spaces on new line, but keep the line

Tags: vb.net

I wish to remove spaces from lines that doesn't contain text, but not remove the line. Since a space character can be hard to identify, I will replace the space character with the "#" (hastag character) to showcase the example easier. The string looks something like this:

```vb
"This is
########a long string
with many lines
#######
and the above is empty
####this is empty
#############
#######hello"
```

I wish that the output would remove the spaces on the lines that only contains the space character. I am still using the "#" (hastag character) to showcase the spaces. The final output should look like this:

```vb
"This is
########a long string
with many lines

and the above is empty
####this is empty

#######hello"
```

Without the hashtag character acting as the space character, the expected output should look like this:

```vb
"This is
        a long string
with many lines

and the above is empty
    this is empty

       hello"
```

So to fully clarify, I wish to remove space characters on a line that doesn't contain text, but not remove the line.

Comment: You would like to remove the space characters and replace them with what?

Comment: I've updated my answer and converted the C# code to VB. I realized too late that you are using VB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your example with octothorpes (yet another name for #) and replacing them with spaces in the code, we can use the [`String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.isnullorwhitespace?view=netcore-3.1) function to check for such lines and replace them with empty strings:

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim s = "This is
########a long string
with many lines
#######
and the above is empty
####this is empty
#############
#######hello"
        s = s.Replace("#", " ")
        Dim t = String.Join(vbCrLf, s.Split({vbCrLf}, StringSplitOptions.None).
                            Select(Function(a) If(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(a), "", a)))

        Console.WriteLine(t)

        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Module
```

Outputs:

```
This is
        a long string
with many lines

and the above is empty
    this is empty

       hello
```

Comment: Out of all of the posts, yours was the only one that worked for me. Thank you for all of the help Andrew! I am sorry to bother you, but do you have any good resource for learning the IEnumerable - Selector and others related to it? I have been wanting to get into that for a while now.

Comment: There's [Introduction to LINQ (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/concepts/linq/introduction-to-linq) and its related pages. I prefer to use [Method-Based](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/method-based-query-examples-linq-to-dataset) syntax. The documentation often contains good examples, but you may need to change the language to VB.NET - it's the link that defaults to "C#" at the top-right of the documentation pages.

Comment: Thank you Andrew! I will check it out!

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code:

```
Dim container As String = IO.File.ReadAllText("test.txt")

container = container.Replace(vbNewLine, vbCr).Replace(vbLf, vbCr)
Do While container.Contains(vbCr & vbCr)
    container = container.Replace(vbCr & vbCr, vbCr)
Loop

If container.StartsWith(vbCr) Then container = container.TrimStart(Chr(13))
container = container.Replace(vbCr, vbNewLine)

IO.File.WriteAllText("test.txt", container)
```

It'll trim all the empty new lines and override the file (before vs. after):

> **Note:** If you want to remove the hashes and replace that with white spaces too, just use the following:

```
Dim container2 As String = 
    My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("test.txt").Replace("#", " ")
IO.File.WriteAllText("test.txt", container2)
```

[image: Before] [image: After]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, however, I may think you have misunderstood the question. I wish to remove the "space" characters (" ") from each line if the line only contains the space character. I do not wish to remove the line.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Dim myString = "your multiline string here"
Dim finalString As String
For each line In myString.Split(CChar(vbNewLine))
    finalstring &= line.Trim() & vbNewLine
Next
```